# Reputation graph does not update when question is deleted

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation-graph

Yesterday I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771499/need-help-finding-out-why-my-insert-to-a-binary-search-tree-keeps-making-duplica) and got 10 rep (at least that's what I remember, the question were deleted and I have <10k rep), but after the question deletion my [reputation graph (in summary)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520779/mgibsonbr?tab=summary) still shows it:

[image: screenshot of rep. graph and rep. changes]

The [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520779/mgibsonbr?tab=reputation) shows the correct value, as the screenshot above shows.

Comment: Really Good caught.